# Problem using Vuetify datatables + single selection prop with template

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Morning!

I'm trying to use the prop 'single-select' in a Vuetify data-table, but I'm facing a problem that I don't know if it's an issue.

Right now, I use a template for the body of the table:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="proveedoresByString"
  :single-select="singleSelect" show-select v-model="itemSelected">
     <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
            <tbody>
              <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
                <!--<td><v-checkbox v-model="itemSelected" :value="item"></v-checkbox></td>-->
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ item.code }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ item.movil }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ item.phone }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center">{{ item.email }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-center" v-if="!item.emailList"
                    v-on="on">{{ item.accesoApp === '0' ? 'No' : 'Yes('+ item.appAccess + ')' }}</td>
                <v-tooltip max-width="320px" bottom v-if="item.emailList">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <td class="text-xs-center" v-on="on">{{ item.appAccess === '0' ? 'No' : 'Si ('+ item.accesoApp + ')' }}</td>
                  </template>
                  <span>{{ item.emailList }}</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Right here, the prop doesn't work, and the piece of code that contains the v-checkbox element doesn't work as a single selector, it selects every row you click.

So, If someone can help to make the single selection prop work it would be awesome or a clue about how to make the checkbox works as a single selector would be nice too.

Thanks!

EDIT: The script part:

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
import rulesMixin from '../../generic/rules'

export default {
  mixins: [rulesMixin],
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: true,
      itemSelected: [],
      headers: [
        { text: this.$t('m_codigo'), value: 'code', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$t('m_nombre'), value: 'name', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$t('m_movil'), value: 'movil', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$t('m_telefono'), value: 'phone', sortable: true, align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$t('m_email'), value: 'email', align: 'left' },
        { text: this.$t('m_acceso_app'), value: 'accesoApp', align: 'left' }
      ]
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you show script part?

Comment: I've updated it, thanks!

Comment: ok, your problem is, that you use your custom implementation, so just `single-select` will not work, because you have your own `checkbox` implementation. So you need to handle `itemSelected` on your own. Btw `<td class="text-xs-center" v-if="!item.emailList"
                    v-on="on">{{ item.accesoApp === '0' ? 'No' : 'Yes('+ item.appAccess + ')' }}</td>` this part try to find `on` in your component, but can't

Comment: Yeah, that part you said was part from a v-tooltip tag that I removed to reduce the amount of code and I forgot to remove. Thanks for your answer. I'm implementing what you suggest, let's see how this works, thanks so much!

Comment: So you still need to handle itemSelected by yourself, or just not use template. Do you need to rewrite default component appearance?

Comment: Can you post the solution that worked please, I'm not seeing how to make this work from the suggestion.